# Custom Meta Box calling JS function twice

Tags: metabox

I have a plugin adding a custom meta box to the comments editing page:

```
function on_admin_init() {
add_meta_box( 
'commentrating',
__( 'Voto recensione', FB_DT_TEXTDOMAIN ),
array( &$this, 'meta_box_voto' ),
'comment', 'normal', 'high'
);
}
function meta_box_voto($data) {
...
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
    alert("ah!");       
});
</script>
<?php
} ...
```

But the alert is called twice! Is this a WP or jQuery bug? Am I making any mistake?

Thanks!

P.S.
If I put the alert into the first function it is only called once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the JS in the `admin_footer`. If the Widgets are moved, your JS tag code can be duplicated hence called twice.

Comment: Great, I love you!